# Performance on low notes

Tags: performing

I'm 15 years old and was wondering what would be some good exercises for a bass singer. My current vocal range is Bb1-F5

Comment: Exercises for what?  Extending your range?  Warm ups?

Comment: Sure and something also to help me be more resonate

Comment: I'm voting to close as a possible duplicate.  The OP should search the site for similar questions - I know I've answered at least 3-4 similar questions in the past about singing range.  Also, to the OP, singing range should include notes that can be sung in a concert / soloistic setting, not all the notes you believe you are capable of producing.

Comment: Ditto for the close. Suggestion to user23775: in your search, use *resonant* or *resonance* rather than *resonate*, this may give you more and better results.  //  Note, you can always come back and post again if you want to ask something more specific or slightly different, just make sure to include a link to a related question you found that *doesn't* exactly meet your needs.